# LED issues in high bay applications

Tags: light-fixture

I have a linear high bay that is 240 watts putting out about 27,000 lumens, we have added a bi-level sensor to the fixture and what's happening is that when the fixture times out the fixture goes off except for about 6" of one board, after about 6 seconds the fixture does go completely off.
The other thing we have noticed is that in one application we had a ghosting issue the fixture's went to about 10%  and did not shut off at all.
HELP !!

Comment: This sounds like an issue with a specific product, have you attempted to contact the vendor?

Comment: You need more details about the product you're talking about.  What is a "linear high bay"?  What is a "bi-level sensor" and how is that connected?  What does it mean for the fixture to "time out"?  Right now it sounds very specific indeed.

Comment: Some occupancy sensors do not play well with LED drivers. It sounds like this may be the case make sure it is rated to drive the linear lighting / LED. Also make sure the fixture is dim-able some are not. High bay usually over 20'.  linear LED type of lamp that fits in old florescent fixtures with new driver. Bi-level = high and low output to fixture.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect the bi-level sensor and see if the fixture behaves normally.

Disconnect any other controls and wire the fixture direct to supply to verify that it works properly without occupancy controls.

Troubleshooting is a process of elimination.

Good luck!